# Find and replace only if it matches a string in vi editor

Tags: vi

I have a large file:

```
.
..
...
        {
        "term": "Allow A to B",
        "to_zone" : ["inside"],
        "from_zone" : ["sys"],
        "source" : ["10.10.10.10/32"],
        "destination": ["20.20.20.20/32","30.30.30.30/32"],
        "source_user" : ["any"],
        "category" : ["any"],
        "application" : ["any"],
        "service" : ["application-default"],
        "source_hip" : ["any"],
        "destination_hip" : ["any"],
        "tag" : ["con"],
        "action" : "allow",
        "rule_type" : ["universal"],
        "group_tag" : ["con"],
        "profile_setting" : "alert-only"
        },
...
..
.
```

I would like to delete only the square brackets '[,]' and leave the quotes quotes ONLY if it matches the line, 'group_tag'.

The expected result would be:

```
.
..
...
        {
        "term": "Allow A to B",
        "to_zone" : ["inside"],
        "from_zone" : ["bdd"],
        "source" : ["10.10.10.10/32"],
        "destination": ["20.20.20.20/32","30.30.30.30/32"],
        "source_user" : ["any"],
        "category" : ["any"],
        "application" : ["any"],
        "service" : ["application-default"],
        "source_hip" : ["any"],
        "destination_hip" : ["any"],
        "tag" : ["con"],
        "action" : "allow",
        "rule_type" : ["universal"],
        "group_tag" : "con",
        "profile_setting" : "alert-only"
        },
...
..
.
```

How do I accomplish this in vi editor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply a substitution to lines matching a pattern:

```
:/group_tag/s/[\[\]]//g
```

The `[\[\]]` matches a literal open or closing square bracket.

To get all such lines in one go, I think you'd have to use this approach:

```
:%s/\(^.*group_tag" : \)\[\(.*\)\]\(.*\)/\1\2\3/g
```

This is matching the whole line, but remembering (using capture groups: `\(`
and `\)`) everything except the square brackets. Then we replace the line with
only the remembered capture groups.

But also see the approaches in [this
question](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/13464/how-to-execute-command-on-every-matching-pattern-not-just-lines).

Comment: I have to keep entering the above line for the next match. Is there a way I can replace all at once in one shot?